# How can I distribute rewards to stakers proportionally?

Tags: staking, reward

I am creating a smart contract where users can stake tokens and a reward is distributed proportional to the amounts users have staked. I can use simple division to keep track of the reward when the user wants to withdraw:

`reward * amountStaked/totalStaked`.

This does not suffice, because the user can re-execute this withdraw function. So we need to keep track of how much they received:

`reward * amountStaked/totalStaked - rewardReceived`

Now, when a new user enters the pool, they should not receive any of the old rewards, as they were distributed over the token holders. We can keep track of this using a rewardMask variable, the amount of rewards already accumulated in the pool and subtract that from the calculation:

`(reward - rewardMask) * amountStaked/totalStaked - rewardReceived`

But now I am running into another issue that I can't solve. When other users join the pool, they dilute the pool. The new users won't be able to receive the rewards from it, but the old users still receive less.

So let's say we have 3 users that each have a stake of 1 token and I want to distribute 3 tokens (to make it easy), each user should get 1 token as a reward and we see this in our calculation. But if another user now joins the pool (with 1 token for example), they themselves won't get the reward, because of the `rewardMask`. But the other people should be able to get the same reward as before, which they don't.

Who can help me solve this issue?